# Help with asp.net mvc 1.0 or 2 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I currently joined a team that is working on an asp.net mvc 1.0 app.

The app is quite large so changing to mvc 2 right now is not an option.

I have visual studio 2010 Ultimate which doesnt come with mvc 1.

When I tried running opening the solution in my computer I got a conversion wizard. I tried following it but the app just doesnt compile.. it gives plenty of errors and they are all related to mvc 2 new additions

My question is.
Can you run asp.net mvc 1 apps in Visual Studio 2010?
thanks ind advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same frowning eye brows when I encountered that. A simple download and install of [ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en) is what you need.

> The app is quite large so changing to mvc 2 right now is not an option.

Did you try? Mostly 2.0 just adds new cool things to 1.0 like areas and better validation (also client side). It's of course your decision but if the architecture team lets you I suggest you try to upgrade and continue on that.

Comment: I did try... some Json errors and some ValueProvider errors that my peers arent getting

Comment: Strange, I suggest you set up a separate question/thread up about it.

Comment: We had similar problems, but I HIGHLY suggest you recommend your team upgrade.  Our app is just under 1 Million lines of code, and has >150 views ... but it only took 3 hours one night to upgrade.  That's not bad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [ASP.Net MVC 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en).

Comment: I have installed it but when I go to File New Project I still dont get asp.net mvc application.. just mvc2.